# Azure DevOps build pipeline - npm ci - Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have Azure DevOps build pipeline configured to build NPM application, that includes the following tasks:

1. Install Node.js (Node.js tool installer) - Version Spec 10.x
2. npm ci (npm task)

And it almost always fails on the `npm ci` task, with error:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '` and then some random string, each time different.

[image]

If I re-run the job manually, it will works. Then, at the next build, it fails again (until I manually rerun it again).

I am also using Azure Artifacts feed with configured Upstream sources to `https://registry.npmjs.org/` and `npm ci` task is configured to use packages from this registry.

[image]

I have tried to:

1. remove Artifacts feed and create a new one
2. remove `Install Node.js` task
3. change node version
4. change `npm ci` to `npm install`

and nothing works. How else can I fix that?

## EDIT - 03 April 2020

Here is my package.json - I've removed some of the private data.
There are two private packages, `@project-name/jodit-vue` and `@project-name/vuex-orm-plugin-axios` hosted on Azure Artifacts - those are forks of `jodit-vue` and `vuex-orm-plugin-axios` with some customizations.

Also, less builds failed recently. About one in 8 builds fails now.

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@project-name/jodit-vue": "^1.2.4-fix",
    "@project-name/vuex-orm-plugin-axios": "0.5.0",
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^5.4.2",
    "@vuex-orm/core": "^0.33.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartjs-plugin-colorschemes": "^0.4.0",
    "core-js": "^3.4.8",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "drag-drop-touch": "^1.3.0",
    "emoji-mart-vue-fast": "^6.1.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.14",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
    "shepherd.js": "^5.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.0",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-cookie-law": "^1.8.0",
    "vue-cropperjs": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.15.1",
    "vue-matomo": "^3.13.0-0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.3.0",
    "vue-recaptcha": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vue-stripe-elements-plus": "^0.2.8",
    "vuejs-logger": "^1.5.3",
    "vuetify": "^1.5.21",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2",
    "vuex-oidc": "^3.3.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.7.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.7.4",
    "@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader": "^0.4.1",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.13",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^5.3.13",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3.13",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.13",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^5.3.13",
    "@storybook/vue": "^5.3.13",
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.6",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.43",
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.47",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.119",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.46",
    "@types/sinon": "^7.0.13",
    "@types/stripe": "^5.0.24",
    "@types/stripe-v3": "^3.0.8",
    "@types/webpack": "^4.4.14",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.6",
    "@vue/cli": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.1.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-is": "^16.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "sinon": "^7.4.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.7",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4",
    "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "^0.6.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-storybook": "^1.2.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

### SOLVED (partially) - 15 April 2020

I have changed `npm ci` to `npm install` a few days ago. No more fails, every build finished successfully since this change.
`install` is slower that `ci` but we can spend one more minute in each build but be sure that it will not fail.

Comment: Can you try removing dependency on the Artifacts feeds? Just a thing to try out to ensure when you run manually, it may not be picking your AuthN to read packages.

Comment: I saw you are using private agent to run this pipeline. Did you ever try with using Hosted agent?

Comment: @monish001 I can try to remove Artifacts feed for test purpose, but I can not remove it for long, because there are some private packages required to build the app.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT most of the time I am using hosted Azure Pipelines agent pool with ubuntu-16.04 agent and it still fails from time to time.

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue on my side, but I guess it relevant with one npm package based on the stacktrace the error message displayed. Would you mind give a simple sample to me. If I could reproduce, it would be much better for our team to investigate this abnormal error from backend. Better include your package-lock.json, I guess it is what the error occurred

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I've added package.json. There are two private pacakges (forks of public packages with minor modifications). Also less builds failed in last days - about one of each 8 builds fails now.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I have changed `npm ci` to `npm install` a few days ago. It is slower but work perfectly - not more fails in builds.

Comment: If a change from _npm ci_ to _npm install_ stopped the errors, then maybe the problem was with **package-lock.json** rather than package.json?